# OpenGl dots look like dash

Tags: opengl

What would cause openGL dots to look like dash lines?  I am trying to draw two separate lines. One contains dashes and the other one contain dots. But what is supposed to be the dotted line, appears as dashes when I compile and run my program. Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>      // (or others, depending on the system in use)
//#include <stdlib.h>


void init()
{
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);  /* Set display-window color to white.
                                           r,g,b,alpha alpha 0.0 transparent */
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);       //  Set projection parameters. 
    gluOrtho2D (0.0, 250.0, 0.0, 250.0); // Set display area
}
void lineSegment()
{
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  // Clear display window. color buffer
    glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 1.0);      // Set line segment color to green.
 //glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);  
int p1 [] = {0,80};
int p2 [] = {50, 50};
int p3 [] = {100, 100};
int p4 [] = {150, 75};
int p5 [] = {200, 120};
int p6 [] = {0, 50};
int p7 [] = {50, 100};
int p8 [] = {100,80 };
int p9 [] = {150, 150};
int p10 [] = {200, 60};  
//double width dashed line
 glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
glLineWidth(2);
glLineStipple (1, 0x00FF); /* dashed */
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2iv (p1);
glVertex2iv(p2);
glVertex2iv (p3);
glVertex2iv (p4);
glVertex2iv (p5);

 glDisable (GL_LINE_STIPPLE); 
 glEnd();

 glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 1.0);      // Set line segment color to green.
 glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);         
glLineWidth(3);
glLineStipple (1, 0x0101); /* dotted */
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2iv (p6);
glVertex2iv(p7);
glVertex2iv (p8);
glVertex2iv (p9);
glVertex2iv (p10);

 glDisable (GL_LINE_STIPPLE);  

glEnd();                      
    glFlush ( );     // Process all OpenGL routines as quickly as possible.

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv);                         // Initialize GLUT.
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);   // Set display mode, single buffering.
    glutInitWindowPosition (50, 100);   // Set top-left display-window position.
    glutInitWindowSize (400, 300);      // Set display-window width and height.
    glutCreateWindow ("Dash and dots "); // Create display window.
    init( );                            // Execute initialization procedure.
    glutDisplayFunc (lineSegment);       // Send graphics to display window.
    glutMainLoop ( );                    // Display everything and wait.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the line width on the dotted line to `1.0`.